# Group by same value and contiguous date

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

```
var myDic = new SortedDictionary<DateTime,int> () 
                { { new DateTime(0), 0 },
                  { new DateTime(1), 1 },
                  { new DateTime(2), 1 },
                  { new DateTime(3), 0 },
                  { new DateTime(4), 0 },
                  { new DateTime(5), 2 }
                };
```

How can group these items (with a LINQ request) like this :

```
group 1 : 
  startDate: 0, endDate:0, value:0
group 2 : 
  startDate: 1, endDate:2, value:1
group 3 : 
  startDate: 3, endDate:4, value:0
group 4 : 
  startDate: 5, endDate:5, value:2
```

group are defined by contiguous date and same values.

Is it possible with a groupby ?

Comment: As a general rule, LINQ either operates on the entire list or a single element of it.  You're asking for it to act based on what's around it, but not the whole list, which is not something it's good at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a keyGenerating function.  This example presumes your dates are already ordered in the source with no gaps.

```
int currentValue = 0;
int groupCounter = 0;

Func<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>, int> keyGenerator = kvp =>
{
  if (kvp.Value != currentValue)
  {
    groupCounter += 1;
    currentValue = kvp.Value;
  }
  return groupCounter;
}

List<IGrouping<int, KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> groups =
  myDictionary.GroupBy(keyGenerator).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to group sequential dates over changes in the value. I don't think you should use linq for the grouping. Instead you should use linq to order the dates and iterate over that sorted list to create your groups.

**Addition 1**
While you may be able to build your collections with by using `.Aggregate()`. I still think that is the wrong approach.

Does your data have to enter this function as a `SortedDictionary`?
I'm just guessing, but these are probably records ordered chronologically.

If so, do this:

```
    public class Record
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Grouper
    {
        public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Record>> GroupRecords(IEnumerable<Record> sortedRecords)
        {
            var groupedRecords = new List<List<Record>>();
            var recordGroup = new List<Record>();
            groupedRecords.Add(recordGroup);

            foreach (var record in sortedRecords)
            {
                if (recordGroup.Count > 0 && recordGroup.First().Value != record.Value)
                {
                    recordGroup = new List<Record>();
                    groupedRecords.Add(recordGroup);
                }

                recordGroup.Add(record);
            }

            return groupedRecords;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So it is not possible with a GroupBy linq request ? Is it possible with a TakeWhile ?

Comment: You might be able to do something with Aggregate(), but I think it's the wrong approach. I am editing my post. Please see the additions.